# Windows explorer does not show devices

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When I open the first explorer, no devices are shown. Only the tree on the left. Every explorer I open after that almost ever shows all devices. The problem is reproducible.

The problem occurs after a complete reboot and hibernate.

Is this a known problem?

This is a Win7 64bit Pro system.

Comment: Maybe you're opening Explorer before the devices have had time to be detected by the system?  What happens if you wait a few minutes before you open the Explorer window?

Comment: What happens if you press F5 inside the window where the devices do not appear?

Comment: Pressing F5 does not help.
It happens not only after reboot but also hours after booting.